# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I want to redirect http://domain.com/index.php?url=controller to http://domain.com/controller. And now it is working correctly. But it doesn't skip directories and files. I made a index2.php file. It also redirect to index.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong variable in you condition. It's not `REQUEST_URI` you need to check, it's `REQUEST_FILENAME`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```